# How to I change the text location on my google map for map clusters in Fluster2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, maps

I'm using google maps to create a bunch of POI on a map. I'm using the Fluster2 library to cluster the POI together when there are too many in a certain location. This all works fine and I'm very happy but I would like to move where the fluster2 text is written so it matches my custom icon. ie: it has a marker with 5 written over it so that you know there are 5 poi under that cluster.

Does anyone know how to change this or set the text to a specific location?

Thanks

The Net Duck

Comment: what does it have to do with ruby-on-rails or ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.div.style.lineHeight = this.style.height + 'px';
```

Change the above line to:

```
this.div.style.lineHeight = this.style.lineHeight + 'px';
```

Now you have control over the position of the text via the lineHeight style. You can now add **'lineHeight: 16'** as a style option when adding Fluster to your application.